# How to count the number of recursions in a stateless service?

Tags: java, spring, loops

Is it possible to count the number of iterations in a service that should not maintain any stateful variables?

```
@Service //stateless spring service singleton
class MyService {
    //this is clearly not stateless
    int iterations = 0;

    ResultVO run() {
        interations++;
        do();
        some();
        subroutines();
        if (validationFails() && iterations <= 3) { 
            run(); //retry the iteration steps only 3 times
        } else {
            throw TooManyIterationsException();
        }
        return resultVO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
@Service //stateless spring service singleton
class MyService {
ResultVO theRun(int iterations) {  // actual execution method
    do();
    some();
    subroutines();
    if (validationFails() && iterations <= 3) { 
        theRun(iterations+1); //retry the iteration steps only 3 times
    } else {
        throw TooManyIterationsException();
    }
    doSomethingWithIterations(iterations);
    return resultVO;
}


    ResultVO run() {   // same name stub as before
       return theRun(0);
    }


}
```

Comment: I also found (just as reference) that spring-batch is providing some wrapper for exactly these usecases. @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html

Answer (score 1):

Pass a count down into the recursion as a parameter, adding 1 each time you call.

Answer (score 0):

You can look examine the stack trace of a new Throwable() and look for the any number of instances of your run() method.

Here is a code snipped that should help:

```
int iterations = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3) 
if (new Throwable().getStackTrace()[i].contains(methodName)) {
  iterations++;
}
```

Comment: he said `should not maintain any stateful variables`

Comment: My code does not maintain any stateful variables, iterations is a local variable, that doe not hold state.

Comment: And the stack is arguably not a stateful variable that the code is actively maintaining... still a horribly ugly solution unless you're in a situation where, for some reason, the depth count absolutely can not be passed down as an argument.